# Exclude unwanted base64 links in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I wrote a simple image scraper script that works in most cases. I came across a website that has some nice `jpg` wallpapers I would like to scrape the links for. The script works fine, but also prints unwanted `base64` data image links. How could I exclude these `base64` links?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/60-most-execellent-ubuntu-wallpapers/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    image = (link.get('src'))
    print image
```

Output:

```
https://assets.hongkiat.com/uploads/60-most-execellent-ubuntu-wallpapers/cloudy-ubuntu-mate.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
https://assets.hongkiat.com/uploads/60-most-execellent-ubuntu-wallpapers/ubuntu-feeling.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
https://assets.hongkiat.com/uploads/60-most-execellent-ubuntu-wallpapers/two-gentlemen-in-car.jpg
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
```

Update.
Thanks for the help. So completed code would look like this to download all the images. Cheers :)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/60-most-execellent-ubuntu-wallpapers/')
img_url = 'https://assets.hongkiat.com/uploads/60-most-execellent-ubuntu-wallpapers/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

for link in soup.select('img[src$=".jpg"]'):
    image = (link['src'])
    image_name = (img_url + image).split('/')[-1]
    print ('Downloading: {}'.format(image_name))
    r2 = requests.get(image)
    with open(image_name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(r2.content)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot. It will fetch you the desired results. I used `.select()` here instead of `.find_all()`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/60-most-execellent-ubuntu-wallpapers/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

for link in soup.select('img[src$=".jpg"]'):
    print(link['src'])
```

Or if you prefer to do the same using `.find_all()`:

```
for link in soup.find_all('img'):
    if ".jpg" in link['src']:
        print(link['src'])
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. So using select instead of find_all in this case after all? And `('img[src$=".jpg"]')` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
  
htmldata = urlopen('https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/60-most-execellent-ubuntu-wallpapers/')
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(htmldata, 'html.parser')

result = soup.find_all('img' , src=re.compile(r".*?(?=jpeg|png|jpg)"))
```